# Unmappable character for encoding Cp1252 when trying to compile Java program

Tags: java, cp1252

I tried making a `Hello World` program in Java, but am getting a `CP1252` error:

```
import acm.program.*; 
public class test extends Program
{
    public void run() { println(”Hello world!!!”); }
}
```

Here's the errors:

```
C:\>javac -cp acm.jar test.java
test.java:4: error: unmappable character for encoding Cp1252
public void run() { println(ÔÇ?Hello world!!!ÔÇ?);
                              ^
test.java:4: error: unmappable character for encoding Cp1252
public void run() { println(ÔÇ?Hello world!!!ÔÇ?);
                                               ^
test.java:4: error: ';' expected
public void run() { println(ÔÇ?Hello world!!!ÔÇ?);
                                          ^
test.java:4: error: not a statement
public void run() { println(ÔÇ?Hello world!!!ÔÇ?);
                                             ^
test.java:5: error: reached end of file while parsing
}
 ^
5 errors`
```

The simple `test.java` program is obviously correct and I don't know what the issue is.

How do I resolve the CP1252 encoding error?

Comment: Use " in stead of ``

Comment: You're using smart quotes, you should be using a normal quote (for an US/UK English keyboard, this would be the key immediately to the left of the `Enter` key).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you're using smart quotes instead of the actual quote character.

Here's a 'fixed' version of your code:

```
import acm.program.*; 
public class test extends Program
{
    public void run() { println("Hello world!!!"); }
}
```

Note the difference between `"` and `”`.

To fix this (and it depends on your keyboard, I think), you should be using the `"` character that's immediately to the left of your `Enter` key.

Comment: @MariosAth You'll need to conduct a google search and Stack Overflow search for this issue, and if it's an issue, post a new question.